# Add/Delete words after/before matched pattern

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am converting some source code from VB6.0 to C#. Apart from the logic, some syntactical differences can be easily replaced while keeping function and variable names intact. For example

**VB 6.0**

```
 1. Dim Amount as Decimal
 2. On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 3. ErrorHandler:
 4. Private Function ValidateValues(Value1 As String, Value2 As Integer)
    as Boolean
```

**C#**

```
 1. decimal Amount;
 2. try {
 3. catch(Exception ex) {
 4. private bool ValidateValues(string Value1, int Value2) {
```

Look at the 4th line which is not simple find and replace. It requires some insertions and deletions before and after a matching pattern.

Help is required in this kind of replacements. Any supporting tool/technique could be referred but I would prefer Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

use this online tools for convert vb to c# :

```
http://converter.telerik.com/
```

Also this tools provide conversion c# to VB code.

Comment: I am doing VB 6.0 to C#, not VB.NET to C#.